# Want to add a product quantity drop down on cehckout page: Magento

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I want to add a quantity drop down for the products on checkout page that user can select as much products from there. This is because i am using one page checkout and i have skipped the cart page: the product price will automatically updated when number of products selected.

I have tried this code to be added in checkout template but nothing coming up:

```
<select class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty">
    <?php $i = 1 ?>
    <?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
        <?php echo $i?>
        <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($i <=   (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()) ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope work for you...

```
<select class="qty" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>">
   <?php
    $total = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
     for ($x=1; $x<=$total; $x++) {
      echo '<option value="' . $x . '">' . $x . '</option>';
     }
   ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try second one, and proper debug

```
 <select class="qty" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>">

<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($_product);
$total = $_item->getQty();
 for ($x=1; $x<=$total; $x++) {
  echo '<option value="' . $x . '">' . $x . '</option>';
 }
?>
</select>
```